# Rewrite final part of URL from KEYCLOAK login page

Tags: nginx, keycloak, openresty

I have set up a docker with keycloak and openresty to handle the accounts with Nginx as web server.
Everything works as intended but my only issue is that I cant find a way to rewrite the URL of Keycloack login page

I need to rewrite this

```
http://test-site.myown.lan:8080/auth/realms/test-site/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=test-login&state=56ccae05bad8e93b09297c3907db9591&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest-site.int.master.lan%2Flogin%2Fcallback&nonce=4f1ecb367a9067e5697812c48f2f9b9e&scope=openid%20email%20profile
```

into this

```
http://test-site.myown.lan/auth/realms/test-site
```

so shortening the last part and hide the port.

I tried the rewrite rule but I havent see any change in the URL.

How do I achieve this?

Edit:
this is the Nginx config

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
add_header          X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

include            /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/mime.types;
#default_type        application/octet-stream;

# set search paths for pure Lua external libraries (';;' is the default path):
lua_package_path '${prefix}/lualib/ngx/?.lua;${prefix}/lualib/resty/?.lua;;';
# set search paths for Lua external libraries written in C (can also use ';;'):
lua_package_cpath '${prefix}/lualib/?.so;${prefix}/luajit/lib:/?.so;;';
# use internal dns as hostname resolver
resolver xxxxxxxxxx;
# cache for discovery metadata documents
lua_shared_dict discovery 1m;
# cache for JWKs
lua_shared_dict jwks 1m;
# Turning Lua Code Cache Off
lua_code_cache off;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.myown.lan;
    return 301 https://test-site.myown.lan:443$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen      443 ssl default_server;

  server_name test-site.myown.lan;
    root        /opt/nginx/html;

    # Disabled caching so the browser won't cache the site.
    expires     0;
    add_header      Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header      Cache-Control "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";

    # enables SSLv3/TLSv1, but not SSLv2 which is weak and should no longer 
  be used.

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.key;
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # set session secret
    set $session_secret secret;




  location / {
    access_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/lua/cs-login.lua;


  }

  location /assets {
    root       /opt/nginx/html;
  }

  # redirect server error pages to the static pages
  error_page 401 /401.html;
  location = /401.html {
    root       /opt/nginx/html;
  }
  error_page 403 /403.html;
  location = /403.html {
    root       /opt/nginx/html;
  }
  error_page 404 /404.html;
  location = /404.html {
    root       /opt/nginx/html;
  }
  error_page 405 /405.html;
  location = /405.html {
    root       /opt/nginx/html;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root       /opt/nginx/html;
  }


  location /name2 {
    root       /opt/html;
    access_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/lua/name2.lua;
  }


  location /name4 {
    root       /opt/html;
    access_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/lua/name4.lua;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean *rewrite*? or *redirect*?  Can you show the code/config you have at the moment then it might be clear why it's not working.

Comment: I actually need that the URL is changed into the second one, not showing all the protocol/openid-connect response etc. I dont know which is the best method, rewrite or redirect, im pretty new to Nginx

Comment: Yeah it can get confusing. A rewite will change the URL before you proxy it onward to another location, so that's only relevant if your server is doing something itself with the changed URL.  A redirect will send the changed URL back to the client to make a new request with that, so that's only relevant if you could navigate to that changed address from your browser.  Do you know which of those scenarios fits in your case?

Comment: I would say the redirect is my case, I just need to truncate the last part of the URL

Comment: Can you paste your docker file and nginx confs? Blank out any sensitive parts, but it's difficult without seeing what you have so far.

Comment: I edited with my nginx config file